# What's the optimal way of making these AJAX GET requests with jQuery & JSON API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api

I'm outputting API data on separate pages coming from different end point urls, ie. `https://api.server.com/first`, `https://api.server.com/second`, etc.

The code is working, but it seems awfully redundant and I'm sure there's a better way of expressing this that's more optimal and faster:

```
var $rubys = $('#rubys');

$(function () {
   $('#loading-rubys').show();
   $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'https://api.server.com/first/',
       success: function(rubys) {
           $.each(rubys, function(i, ruby) {

$rubys.append('$'+parseFloat(ruby.price).toFixed(2)+' | 
$'+parseFloat(ruby.attribute).toFixed(0));
           });
       },
       complete: function(){
       $('#loading-rubys').hide();
       }
   })
});    

var $emeralds = $('#emeralds');

$(function () {
   $('#loading-emeralds').show();
   $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'https://api.server.com/second/',
       success: function(emeralds) {
           $.each(emeralds, function(i, emerald) {

$emeralds.append('$'+parseFloat(emerald.price).toFixed(2)+' | 
$'+parseFloat(emerald.attribute).toFixed(0));
           });
       },
       complete: function(){
       $('#loading-emeralds').hide();
       }
   })
});
```

The following:

```
var $rubys = $('#rubys');
$('#loading-rubys').show();
```

are set for each post page using YAML front-matter (Jekyll) like so:

```
---
title: Post about Ruby
var-id: rubys
load-id: loading-rubys
---
```

and output them in HTML:

```
 <div id="{{ page.var-id }}">   
 <div id="{{ page.load-id }}">
     <img src="/assets/img/loading.svg"/>
 </div>
 </div>
```

**Current workflow**

So basically whenever I create a new post, I:

- Set the `var-id` and `load-id` custom parameters for each post in the front-matter
- Create a new function to include those and make a new GET request to the respective url, ie. `https://api.server.com/third/`, `https://api.server.com/fourth/`.

**How would you write this better?**

Comment: Questions like this are off topic here at stackoverflow.  You should consider asking it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could help.

```
function getGems(gems,gemsURL) {
var $gems = $('#'+gems);
$('#loading-'+gems).show();
   $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: gemsURL,
       success: function(data) {
           $.each(data, function(i, v) {
               $gems.append('$'+parseFloat(v.price).toFixed(2)+' | 
               $'+parseFloat(v.attribute).toFixed(0));
           });
       },
       complete: function(){
       $('#loading-'+gems).hide();
       }
   });
}
$(function () {
    getGems('rubys','https://api.server.com/first/');
    getGems('emeralds','https://api.server.com/second/')
});
```

Comment: Yes, it's perfect! Working exactly as expected. Learned a lot today, thanks again @PeterDarmis.